# Navigate to differents tabs on recordPage

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want navigate to diffents tabs of a record.
I need 3buttons for navigate to opportunity:

- Navigate to Activity tab (default tab of flexipage)
- Navigate to Chatter tab - Activity
- Navigate to Details tab - Activity

The second and third buttons are possible??
Thanks

[image]

With this example, I can navigate to the hardcode opportunity. The open tab is activity (default on flexipage)

cmp:

```
<lightning:button label="Activity" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
```

controller:

```
handleClick: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        window.location.href = '/lightning/r/Opportunity/0060E00000HzcddQAB' + '/view';
    }
```

Post related with: [Redirect to non-default tab on recordpage from Lightning Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263469/redirect-to-non-default-tab-on-recordpage-from-lightning-component)

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible in standard Component , you can achieve your use case if you build custom lightning component with [workspaceAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation)

Comment: what method must be used? I don´t see any method to redirect a tab of the flexipage. Thanks